# SQL Server Duplicate Transactions

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I need to report different customers having the same PO number. I can achieve this with the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    TX1.Id, TX2.Id
FROM 
    Transactions TX1
INNER JOIN 
    Transactions TX2 ON TX1.Cus_Id <> TX2.Cus_Id AND T1.Po_Num = T2.Po_Num
```

I self join (`INNER JOIN`) the `Transactions` table and it successfully identifies records having a different customer id but the same PO number. The problem is that the result will include duplicate information, for instance:

Result

[image]

I am looking for a proper way to avoid the redundancy (this is for an automated report).

Comment: I believe that's ok

Comment: You believe what is ok @techspider?

Comment: @Hogan - ha ha; I didn't understand the question until I read your answer!! Is that really OP wants to eliminate duplicate sets (2,3 and 3,2 / 5,8 and 8,5) from results?

Comment: @techspider -- I think so -- that is what he says it results in duplicate information... do you see another way it is duplicate?

Comment: @Hogan I thought OP wants to find if using `DISTINCT` in that query is good enough or are there any alternatives?

Comment: @techspider well we won't know till he comments -- but he left for a long weekend, so I hope he enjoys the beach. :)

Comment: @Hogan you are right. It happened on another question also today for OP to come out of vacation ;)

Comment: @Hogan awww.. you are a star here!! :)

Comment: @techspider - lol thanks -- but I was wrong about the beach!

Comment: @Hogan - lol... I missed my bounty before my vacation...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a where

```
SELECT DISTINCT TX1.Id, TX2.Id
FROM Transactions TX1
INNER JOIN Transactions TX2 ON TX1.Cus_Id <> TX2.Cus_Id AND T1.Po_Num = T2.Po_Num 
WHERE TX1.Id < TX2.Id
```

This will give you the "first half" of your current result.

Comment: Oh well...I am not sure why I didn't figure that out sooner. Thanks a lot!